# Excel VBA: Save workbook as Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, save-as

I would like to save my workbook (all sheets) as one Word document.
One sheets it's one page in document.

I find only code for save activeSheet.

```
Sub ExcelToWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim objWd As Object
Set objWd = CreateObject("word.application")
objWd.Visible = True
Dim objDoc As Object
Set objDoc = objWd.Documents.Add
objDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1 '  portrait = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws.UsedRange.Copy
objDoc.Content.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
objDoc.SaveAs (Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\dokument.docx")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The code seems to be just doing a copy/paste, so just loop through each worksheet doing the copy/paste before doing the save.

Comment: Yes, i think the same, but my script save only last page (sheet).

    n = Sheets.Count
    For i = 1 To n
    Sheets(i).UsedRange.Copy
    objDoc.Content.Paste
    Next i

Answer (score 2):

A couple quick things will get you to a solution.

The first is to loop through the worksheets in your workbook, like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Debug.Print "The used range is " & ws.UsedRange.Address
Next ws
```

The next part is to understand how adding content to a Word document is accomplished. The main concept involves where the insertion point for the document is located -- generally this is the current `Selection`.

When you cut and paste into a Word document, the content just pasted is still "selected". This means that any subsequent paste will effectively replace what you just inserted. So you have to move the selection point to the end of the document.

Putting it all together in an example program:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExcelToWord()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    '--- create the Word document
    Dim objWd As Word.Application
    Set objWd = CreateObject("word.application")
    objWd.Visible = True

    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Set objDoc = objWd.Documents.Add
    objDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1             '  portrait = 0

    Const wdPageBreak As Long = 7

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        ws.UsedRange.Copy
        objWd.Selection.Paste
        '--- advance the selection point to the end of
        '    the document and insert a page break, then
        '    advance the insertion point past the break
        objDoc.Characters.Last.Select
        objWd.Selection.InsertBreak wdPageBreak
        objDoc.Characters.Last.Select
    Next ws
    'objDoc.SaveAs Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & ".\dokument.docx"
End Sub
```